# How are mutations gained?

Tags: only-war

How mutations are gained in *Only War* is vague compared to the other 40k RPGs. The maladies are clearly explained, so why the vagueness on mutation. Have there been any official clarifications on how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A character who becomes corrupted and fails their tests to resist mutation gains a Trait chosen by the GM to represent their mutation

As in the other WH40K RPG games, the most likely way to gain mutations is by gaining corruption points due to exposure to Chaos and the Warp. The Only War rulebook, on pages 308-309, describes the effects of gaining Corruption. The first is that for every 10 CP gained, the character must make a **malignancy test** or suffer some sort of mental affliction. However, for every 30 CP gained, the character must test to resist physical mutation:

> For every 30 Corruption Points a character gains, he must make a Test against two Characteristics of his choice or suffer a Minor Mutation (in the form of a Trait). He may not Test against the same Characteristic twice to resist mutation.

Individual mutations are not described in this section of the rules, though. The GM is directed to the Traits section (starting on page 154) to choose a Trait to grant the character to represent their mutation, though the passage does suggest some appropriate options from that chapter, and it is up to the GM to describe the physical form of the mutation.

Unusually for this game line, there's no table you can roll against to randomly choose a mutation - it's all left up to the GM. However, there's nothing really stopping you from re-using the Minor/Major mutation tables from Dark Heresy (or other WH40K RPG lines) if you'd rather retain the random factor. Unfortunately, it's not clear why the writers of Only War decided not to include such an option in that book and speculating why is beyond the scope of this site.